Is there e2e testing framework/example for Substrate solo chain?
I am working on a live solo chain. I have to test a scenario where I want to hit HTTP API through off chain-worker. Unfortunately it's not possible to test in mock environment.
We can take an example of official Substrate Offchain example where we are hitting price api. I want to test whether we are able to hit price api through off chain.
I just wanted to check if there is any framework or example for e2e test for Substrate solo chain?

Hi @boleng, can you share more information about your scenario since I think you could use zombienet to make it. Thanks!

@pepoviola I just edited my question. Please take a look. Can we use zombienet to test off chain?
